# can i send empty cookie to browser?

Tags: html, perl, cookies, session-cookies

from my perl program, I am sending response to AJAX calls like this:

```
...a lot of code...
$| = 1;
print $q->header(-type=>'text/html',-cookie=>$cookie);
my $tt = Template->new({INCLUDE_PATH => $htmlTempletPath});
$tt->process($returnVal,$ttVars)|| die $tt->error();
1;
```

When user first login, i set and send this $cookie as session ID etc. for auth purposes. Whenever i increase expire-time on cookie, i send it back thru -cookie=> directive.

my concern is, if $cookie variable is empty, how does it affect the browser/session or the cookie which is already setup? Or does the browser silently ignore -cookie=> (empty)

Pl advice. I looked around but found no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed in the normative documentation for cookies, RFC6265

> If the user agent receives a new cookie with the same cookie-name,
> domain-value, and path-value as a cookie that it has already stored,
> the existing cookie is evicted and replaced with the new cookie.
> Notice that servers can delete cookies by sending the user agent a
> new cookie with an `Expires` attribute with a value in the past.

So, a cookie is only explicitly removed when it is sent by you with an expiration date in the past. Obviously users and/or user-agents can still remove your cookies for whatever other reason.

#### See also

The HTTP RFC relating to Cookies, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265

Comment: in this case the $cookie variable is empty. It has nothing, no cookie name nothing. So I guess it has no impact on browser or session??

Comment: for expiry/logout, i have a separate cgi which sends back the cookie with 0 sec for expiry and it does its job.

Comment: @rajeev: yes, sending an empty cookie has no effect.